# GLM on compile breeds a ton of errors

Tags: c++, opengl-es, mingw, qmake

I include some GLM files into my code, and I receive a ton of errors (at least 90 of them). Why this is happening, I have no idea. I am using the latest GLM (0.9.3.3 at the time of this writing). I am also using Qt Creator on Windows, with a QMake file you'll see.

I should also note that I ended up copying the glm folder to my include directory reciding in my mingw folder.

What can I do to fix this?

**QMake**

```
CONFIG += console

HEADERS += \
    util.hpp \
    ShaderComparable.hpp \
    SearchTree.hpp \
    FileUtility.hpp \
    Debug.hpp \
    ShaderHandler.hpp \
    Shader.hpp \
    Testing.hpp \
    Sphere.hpp \
    Shape.hpp \
    Circle.hpp \
    Maths.hpp

SOURCES += \
    util.cpp \
    ShaderComparable.cpp \
    SearchTree.inl \
    Main.cpp \
    FileUtility.cpp \
    Debug.cpp \
    ShaderHandler.cpp \
    Testing.cpp \
    Sphere.cpp \
    Shape.cpp \
    Circle.cpp

win32:LIBS += -llibEGL -llibGLESv2
unix: LIBS += -lEGL -lGLESv2

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x -U__STRICT_ANSI__
```

**Errors**

```
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp: In instantiation of 'glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>':
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:82:   instantiated from 'glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>'
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./gtc/swizzle.hpp:114:   instantiated from here
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:79: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::r' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:79: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::r' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:79: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::g' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:79: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::g' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:79: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::b' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:79: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::b' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:79: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::a' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:79: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::a' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:80: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::s' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:80: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::s' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:80: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::t' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:80: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::t' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:80: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::p' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:80: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::p' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:80: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::q' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:80: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::q' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:81: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::x' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:81: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::x' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:81: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::y' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:81: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::y' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:81: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::z' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:81: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::z' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:81: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::w' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec4.hpp:81: error: member 'glm::detail::half glm::detail::tvec4<glm::detail::half>::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::w' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Programming/C++/Qt/qtesc/esc/Debug'
In file included from c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type.hpp:40,
                 from c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/glm.hpp:97,
                 from ../esc/Maths.hpp:3,
                 from ../esc/Sphere.hpp:5,
                 from ../esc/Sphere.cpp:1:
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp: In instantiation of 'glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>':
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:82:   instantiated from 'glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >'
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./virtrev/xstream.hpp:92:   instantiated from here
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::r' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::r' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::r' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::g' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::g' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::g' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::b' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::b' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::b' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::s' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::s' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::s' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::t' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::t' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::t' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::p' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::p' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::p' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::x' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::x' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::x' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::y' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::y' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::y' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::z' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::z' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec3.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec3<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::z' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
In file included from c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type.hpp:39,
                 from c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/glm.hpp:97,
                 from ../esc/Maths.hpp:3,
                 from ../esc/Sphere.hpp:5,
                 from ../esc/Sphere.cpp:1:
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp: In instantiation of 'glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>':
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:82:   instantiated from 'glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >'
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./virtrev/xstream.hpp:92:   instantiated from here
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::r' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::r' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::r' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::g' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::g' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:79: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::g' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::s' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::s' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::s' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::t' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::t' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:80: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::t' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::x' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::x' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::x' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::y' with constructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::y' with destructor not allowed in union
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/glm/glm/./core/type_vec2.hpp:81: error: member 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > glm::detail::tvec2<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::y' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue. It's because glm doesn't work with -std=c++0x. You have to use c++98.

Comment: That makes sense. AFAIK they fixed this issue recently, though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed most of the errors by not including `glm/ext.hpp`, as that appeared to be what was doing the damage. If anyone knows anything about why this is happening, it would be cool to hear from you on this.