# Is GLM compataible with GLload and GCC

Tags: c++, glm-math, glload

I am currently getting my OpenGL 'framework' set up, and have settled on using GLload, mostly for the extension loading, but it has the added benefit of proving a proper 'gl' name space. As such, al gl* functions are instead used as gl::* for example:

```cpp
glUniformMatrix4fv(...) // instead of this
gl::UniformMatrix4fv(...) // use this
```

I also want to make use of glm, which from my understanding, should be as simple as include `glm/glm.hpp` and ensure I tell  my compiler where to find this. But it seems that it may not be compatible directly with glload, for I get the following errors when I try compile with it.

```
In file included from glm/glm/fwd.hpp:32:0,
                 from glm/glm/glm.hpp:91,
                 from src/main.cpp:3:
glm/glm/core/type_int.hpp:220:2: error: redefinition of ‘struct glm::detail::is_int<long int>’
glm/glm/core/type_int.hpp:219:2: error: previous definition of ‘struct glm::detail::is_int<long int>’
glm/glm/core/type_int.hpp:250:2: error: redefinition of ‘struct glm::detail::is_uint<long unsigned int>’
glm/glm/core/type_int.hpp:249:2: error: previous definition of ‘struct glm::detail::is_uint<long unsigned int>’
```

From looking at `type_int.hpp` you can see that it using a macro, first to with 'signed long' and 'unsigned long' respectively, then with 'highp_int_t' and 'highp_uint_t' (causing this error). These two redefining types are 'int64' and 'uint64', which exact types are dependent on compiler. As I am using GCC I believe means I should see these types as 'signed long long' and 'usigned long long'.

If I do comment out these two lines, everything *seems* to compile just fine. Of course, I am sure sooner or later it will turn out I broke something by doing so.

Looking up similar questions took me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266228/300797) answer, that basically says glm does not support being built with `-std=C++11`, which for me is not acceptable; but this answer is nearly two years old, and glm's site does claim full C++11 compatibility.

And for reference, I am using gcc version 4.7.3, glm version 0.9.5 (as pulled from the [github](https://github.com/g-truc/glm) repo), glload from version 0.4.4 of glsdk (I have removed all other 'modules' of the glsdk, leaving me justglload).

Comment: *glm does not support being built with -std=C++11* That's undoubtfully untrue; the library will make use of C++11 features if they are present.

Comment: like I said, that was from an answer nearly two years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be a problem with using version 0.9.5 of GLM.

Thankfully I had used a git submodule, so I was able to test with version 0.9.4 handy enough. It seems that version 0.9.4 is working just fine for me.

Comment: At the time of this post, 0.9.4.4 is the latest official stable release. You were probably using a bleeding edge (development) version.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I suggested.

Comment: Indeed it was, but admitting that makes me look less smart :P